# Xcode: compiled application file does not work as in debug runtime

Tags: swift, xcode

I have an issue where when I run my application in debug mode, the application shows obvious runtime lags. As specified in numerous articles, the application bundle will run up to 10X faster than when running from xcode (including with instruments).

However, when I open the app (going through the project explorer/products/app_name.app) and show in finder then run the app, several features that work perfectly in debug mode (in my case, certain keyboard press functions).

The app runs much faster as expected than the debug mode runtime, but lacks some of the behaviors which work in debug mode. Furthermore, some other actions close the application altogether.

I don't know where to start figuring this out but have some intuition and would like confirmation what it might be:
1-Instruments: is there a difference of memory usage between debug and application bundle for which debug keeps a cap on memory usage, CPU usage etc?
2- COnsidering cache misses, is it possible that my nSResponder when I activate a key does not catch some later down the track switch cases, which will create a cache miss? (I doubt this since my controls file runs as an extension to one of my main loops). Note: If this works fine in debug mode, why would it not work in the application itself?

Any pointer to why this behavior greatly appreciated, so that I don't make large changes that won't affect the outcome (It's a large project).

Comment: "but lacks some of the behaviors which work in debug mode. Furthermore, some other actions close the application altogether." specify?

Answer (score 0):

So are you saying that when you compile for debugging (-ONone), then things work. But when you compile for release then some things don't work?

Comment: Yes, in release some don't work. I'm wondering if this is because one of my sub systems (audio layer engine) generates speech synthesis files which access the file system.

Answer (score 0):

Try unchecking 'Enable backtrace recording' in the Options tab of the Run scheme action.

Comment: Tried it. Though this opened some more understanding on the schemes, it's the same. Are there any sandbox settings I should be aware of? What happens is that when I start the audio layer engine, it takes a few files from the system (created folder at startup if doesn't exist), starts recording services and runs the engine. It works fine in debug or profile mode but not when I open the .app via project/products/name.app (show in finder)